# PHP cli only works with "-n"

Tags: php, linux, composer-php

I'm stuck for days on a PHP CLI problem :

I have no ouptut, just a blank line and the cursor waiting for instructions when I run :

```
php -r "echo 1;"
```

But when I run this line with -n (No php.ini file will be used), everything works :

```
php -nr "echo 1;"
```

My real problem is that my `composer` shortcut (/bin/composer) doesn't work anymore and I have to write `php -n /bin/composer` every time now.

I work on Debian Wheezy and my PHP version is up to date (5.4.4-14).

I reinstalled php many times without success. Please, can you help me ?

Comment: Have you tried checking the system log of errors relating to PHP? There appears to be something wrong with one of your php.ini files. If the system log doesn't display anything, you could look through your ini files commenting out lines until you find the solution.

Comment: @LoganBailey Indeed, I checked the PHP error logs and no errors are logged (except if I intentionally trigger one which is weird cause it means that my php line is well interpreted). I also copied another PHP ini file from another server that works correctly with the exact same PHP version but it didn't change anything.

Comment: What's the exit code after running `php -r "echo 1;"`? (run `echo $?` afterwards).

Comment: @DrewHammond Unfortunately I get no exit code because I am forced to cancel my command with CTRL+C (Which exit codes with 130). When I run my command I just get a new blank line like it was awaiting for more instructions. However, when I trigger a PHP error syntax, the error is logged and my exit code is then 254.

Comment: Weird. Do you have php aliased to something? Try `which php` and `alias php`

Comment: @DrewHammond `which php` returns /usr/bin/php and no alias is found with `alias php`. Furthemore, when I run `/usr/bin/php` directly, I get the exact same issue as when I run `php`. I agree with you that it is really weird. Thank you for helping me by the way.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you have the readline extension enabled? (`php -m | grep readline`)

Comment: @DrewHammond No I have not the readline extension enabled. Do you think it could help ? Maybe I'm wrong but I thought that this extension was more related to a "-i" (interactive mode) issue.

Comment: Yeah it was just a thought. It might be worth trying though. To avoid turning this into 20 questions, I suggest you add some additional information about your environment to the question, i.e., output of `php --ini`, output of `php -v`, and of course you might want to try simply reinstalling php5-cli and php5-common if possible

Comment: Thank you so much @DrewHammond, you found it : I just removed php-common AND php5-cli (I didn't try to uninstall php-common, my bad) and reinstalled and it worked ! I don't know how to accept your answer in stack overflow so I'll post an answer and refer to you in it.

Comment: @JakeGould I just deleted my answer, I didn't know that I couldn't do that, sorry. Thank you for having me explain this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reinstall **`php5-cli`** and **`php5-common`** packages as well as any other dependencies that you need *such as `libssh2-php` as you mentioned above*.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall php5-common php5-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Composer**

Please try to reinstall Composer to your /bin folder.

**Install Composer globally to /bin/composer**

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

mv composer.phar /bin/composer
```

If move fails, use sudo.

**Run Composer**

Then run `/bin/composer`, instead of `php composer.phar` or `php -n /bin/composer`.

If you can't execute, `chmod +x /bin/composer` see [the documentation for more information](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally).

---

**2. PHP CLI**

`php -r "echo 1;"` should return "1" on a new-line.

If this doesn't happen, then you might want to look at the PHP.ini file for the CLI.

When something starts to work with `-n` applied (no ini used + use default settings), it's an indicator that the configuration is messed up.

To get the paths of the loaded ini's: `php --ini` or `php -i | grep 'Configuration File'`.

On Debian the location should be `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`.

Then look for ini directives, which might impact the output, like output_buffering in combination with implicit_flush. output_buffering on the CLI is turned off by default. if output_buffering is accidentally turned on, while implicit_flush is off and you don't flush the buffer manually, you won't see any output.

Ensure error handling directives and logging are turned on: `display_errors`, `display_startup_errors`, `log_errors`.

Comment: Thank you Jens-André but I don't think that my issue is Composer related because my php command line is also affected. And if I run `php -n /bin/composer`, Composer works like a charm. I also have the same problem running the symfony app/console. However, I appreciate how you detailled the Composer installation process in order to use it globally.

Comment: I just wanted to point that out, because you wrote "My real problem is that my composer shortcut ..". You don't need to use "php -n /bin/composer", because the phar file is executable. The command to use composer is "/bin/composer". I append my answer with a hint for the "PHP -r" vs "PHP -nr" problem.

Comment: No problem, I'm aware that the composer.phar is self executable because of its shebang line. My problem is that it is executed without the "-n" parameter so it just does nothing because of my PHP cli issue.I probably misspoke when I said that my problem came from Composer, sorry. I said that because this issue is especially annoying for me when I use composer.

Comment: I just checked my php.ini file for output_buffering as you suggested and you were right that my output_buffering was at 4096 and not Off. My implicit_flush is Off. 

I tried by modifying their values but nothing cames out. I am sure that this php.ini file is the one used by the cli cause when I misformat it i get php.ini error. 

Furthemore, this php.ini file is also used on another server and this one works like a charm when I run a php command. In any case, thank you for helping me.

Comment: That this ini works on another server is mysterious to me. One last thing, before i'm out of ideas: you might do a cleanup or rebuild the PHP.ini from scratch. In other words: start with a reduced set of directives for the CLI which work. Then keep extending the working ini. start with error handling, then add extensions, do not include buffering. all "not included" directives will work with their default settings. Hope you figure it out! Good luck ,)

Comment: It seems a good idea thank you, I'll try that and I'll keep you in touch.

Comment: Unfortunately, I just emptied my php.ini file and launched php with this empty file and it already behaves like before. I really don't get it. I tried to force the php.ini with -c and it didn't work either.

Comment: Oh wow.. "I reinstalled php many times without success." No you did not and i didn't expect that.

Comment: Sorry Jens-André, I reinstalled the php5-cli many times, I didn't try to reinstall all the php packages. But I still don't understand  why this php installation was corrupted. Sorry again